# I don't want WebStorm to remove the spaces between "import { Injectable } ..."

Tags: angular, format, webstorm

When I press `Ctrl + Alt + L` which reformats the code, it converts `import { Injectable }` to `import {Injectable}`. I don't like that. How can I fix it?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { Logger } from '../core';
import enUS from '../../translations/en-US.json';
import bgBG from '../../translations/bg-BG.json';

const log = new Logger('I18nService');
const languageKey = 'language';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class I18nService {
```

### tslint.json

Not sure if it has to be made through WebStorm or the tslint config, so I'm pasting tslint config here, just in case.

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "align": {
      "options": [
        "parameters",
        "statements"
      ]
    },
    "array-type": false,
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "arrow-return-shorthand": true,
    "curly": true,
    "deprecation": {
      "severity": "warning"
    },
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "contextual-lifecycle": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "vex",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "vex",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "eofline": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": {
      "options": [
        "spaces"
      ]
    },
    "interface-name": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-redundant-jsdoc": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-var-requires": false,
    "object-literal-key-quotes": [
      true,
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "semicolon": {
      "options": [
        "always"
      ]
    },
    "space-before-function-paren": {
      "options": {
        "anonymous": "never",
        "asyncArrow": "always",
        "constructor": "never",
        "method": "never",
        "named": "never"
      }
    },
    "trailing-comma": false,
    "no-conflicting-lifecycle": true,
    "no-host-metadata-property": false,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-inputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-output-native": true,
    "no-output-on-prefix": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "no-outputs-metadata-property": true,
    "template-banana-in-box": true,
    "template-no-negated-async": true,
    "typedef-whitespace": {
      "options": [
        {
          "call-signature": "nospace",
          "index-signature": "nospace",
          "parameter": "nospace",
          "property-declaration": "nospace",
          "variable-declaration": "nospace"
        },
        {
          "call-signature": "onespace",
          "index-signature": "onespace",
          "parameter": "onespace",
          "property-declaration": "onespace",
          "variable-declaration": "onespace"
        }
      ]
    },
    "use-lifecycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "variable-name": {
      "options": [
        "allow-pascal-case",
        "allow-leading-underscore"
      ]
    },
    "whitespace": {
      "options": [
        "check-branch",
        "check-decl",
        "check-operator",
        "check-separator",
        "check-type",
        "check-typecast"
      ]
    }
  },
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "codelyzer"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting *WebStorm*'s code style config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure because I don't have the Webstorm editor but found this [link](https://rtmccormick.com/2017/09/29/webstorm-adding-spaces-imports-braces-javascript-typescript/)

Add Spaces Between Import and Braces in Webstorm Settings:

1. Open Settings: File > Default Settings
2. Expand Editor Menu on Left
3. Expand Code Style Menu under Editor Menu
4. Click JavaScript or TypeScript if you are using TypeScript
5. Click on the Spaces Tab in the right content area
6. Scroll Down to Within Settings
7. Select ES6 import/export braces
8. Click Apply and Ok to close